# How to manage color of input field within form in react?

Tags: html, css, forms, input-field

I have a text input field inside a form in my react app that looks like this before being clicked on:

[image]

After I click inside the input field it looks like this:
[image]

I would like the text box to remain the same grayish color when clicked on instead of changing to white. How can I achieve this? This is what I have so far:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(105, 103, 116);
}

.main-search {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-search:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit={this.spinSubmit}>
  <div className="input-field container main-search">
    <input className="main-search-input-field" id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." value={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <button id="btn-submit-search"><i className="material-icons">search</i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have been doing all this testing in Chrome if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the `type` field in my `input` to "text" instead of "search":

```
 <input className="main-search-input-field" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

```
.main-search-input-field {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

To your css file.

Comment: This is something I had already tried and I should have added to my question. Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
input[type="search"], textarea {    
  background-color :rgb(105, 103, 116);
  border:0px;    
}
```

output:

[image]

Another option is to use this. but change "className" to "class"

```
.main-search-input-field, textarea {
  background-color :rgb(105, 103, 116);
  border:0px;
}

 <input class="main-search-input-field" id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." value="search" onChange="" />
```

Comment: In react, we use className instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

In **CSS**:

```
#search{
background: rgb(105, 103, 116);
}
```

Comment: In react, we use className instead of class.

Comment: It is mentioned in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this fiddle - [Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/qc6jxu40/7/)

You only need to apply CSS on your input tag.

```
input[type="search"] {    
 background-color :rgb(105, 103, 116);
 border:0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```